# Difference between :: operator and -> operator in PHP

Tags: php

In Object oriented PHP we use `::` operator and `->` operator to access object in a class. What are the differeces between those two operator beside `::` operator for static and `->` operator for non static. And why there is distinction between those two operator, unlike another programming language which use just `.` (dot) operator for accessing class object?

Comment: because it's different language?

Comment: Because in PHP classes are not objects unlike the other languages you refer to.  Other languages use meta-objects to describe the class, which is how you implement the static operator as you describe.  But in PHP it's a static structure so it's nothing more than an identifier. And since it's nothing more than an identifier, using an instance operator on an identifier wouldn't make sense.

Comment: *(related)* [What does that symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)